# Why Compare and Set in .NET JIT_WriteBarrier over Set

Tags: .net, assembly, garbage-collection, intel

A bit late to the party I decided to read up a bit on how a [generational GC like the one in .NET works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

I decided to look a bit on how the `CardTable` is implemented in .NET and dumped the `x64` code.

```
clr!JIT_WriteBarrier:
00007ff9`401f3e30 488911          mov     qword ptr [rcx],rdx
00007ff9`401f3e33 0f1f00          nop     dword ptr [rax]
00007ff9`401f3e36 48b8181085a50a020000 mov rax,20AA5851018h
00007ff9`401f3e40 483bd0          cmp     rdx,rax
00007ff9`401f3e43 722b            jb      clr!JIT_WriteBarrier+0x40 (00007ff9`401f3e70)
00007ff9`401f3e45 90              nop
00007ff9`401f3e46 48b8a04f307c0a020000 mov rax,20A7C304FA0h
00007ff9`401f3e50 48c1e90b        shr     rcx,0Bh
00007ff9`401f3e54 803c08ff        cmp     byte ptr [rax+rcx],0FFh
00007ff9`401f3e58 7502            jne     clr!JIT_WriteBarrier+0x2c (00007ff9`401f3e5c)
00007ff9`401f3e5a f3c3            rep ret
00007ff9`401f3e5c c60408ff        mov     byte ptr [rax+rcx],0FFh
00007ff9`401f3e60 c3              ret
00007ff9`401f3e61 666666666666660f1f840000000000 nop word ptr [rax+rax]
00007ff9`401f3e70 f3c3            rep ret
00007ff9`401f3e72 6666666666660f1f840000000000 nop word ptr [rax+rax]
00007ff9`401f3e80 f3c3            rep ret
00007ff9`401f3e82 6666666666660f1f840000000000 nop word ptr [rax+rax]
00007ff9`401f3e90 90              nop
clr!JIT_WriteBarrier_End:
```

Not an `x64` programmer (I can read and understand the code somewhat but can't write) a question popped up:

Why compare and set? Why not set?

```
# Checks if flag is set
00007ff9`401f3e54 803c08ff        cmp     byte ptr [rax+rcx],0FFh
00007ff9`401f3e58 7502            jne     clr!JIT_WriteBarrier+0x2c (00007ff9`401f3e5c)
00007ff9`401f3e5a f3c3            rep ret
# Sets flag
00007ff9`401f3e5c c60408ff        mov     byte ptr [rax+rcx],0FFh
```

Instead I would've written it like this:

```
# Sets flag
00007ff9`401f3e5c c60408ff        mov     byte ptr [rax+rcx],0FFh
```

From my simplistic viewpoint always writing `0xFF`would avoid a branch. But perhaps by avoiding a write reduces cache synchronization overhead?

As this function is called whenever a reference field is set one would like to keep the overhead of this function to an absolute minimum.

Comment: Do look at the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/amd64/JitHelpers_Fast.asm#L461) so you can read the comments.  This code is crazily micro-optimized, they paid attention to the processor's pipeline.  A guess is that since the card table isn't often dirty they are intentionally avoiding the write to take pressure off the write buffer.

Comment: Thanks for finding the source. Will check it out.